# What is happening to the column I add?

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to convert data from wide to long. It is pre/ post data for 15 subscales. In the wide version I have "intrinsic_pre" and "intrinsic_post" etc. I want to make faceted boxplots for all the subscales at the end. I thought that adding a new column with pre and post would work.

I convert from long to wide with

```
data_long<-gather(df, subscale, measurement, 23:52)
data_long<-na.omit(data_long)
data_long
```

which seems to work fine. Then I try to add a column for status like so:

```
data_long %>%
  mutate(status = case_when(
    endsWith(subscale, "pre")~"pre",
    endsWith(subscale, "post")~"post"))
is.character(status)
```

which tells me that the status column is there
A tibble: 1,140 x 3
condition     measurement status
                
1 Intrinsic_pre        7    pre
2 Intrinsic_pre        5.75 pre
3 Intrinsic_pre        5    pre
4 Intrinsic_pre        5.3  pre
5 Intrinsic_pre        4.25 pre
6 Intrinsic_pre        4.5  pre
7 Intrinsic_pre        6.3  pre
8 Intrinsic_pre        6.25 pre
9 Intrinsic_pre        6.3  pre
10 Intrinsic_pre        5    pre

but when I go to use it I get the following error

Error: object 'status' not found

Comment: It doesn't look like you are assigning the result of your chain.  If you have assigned it, you would need to reference it using `is.character(data_long$status)` not `is.character(status)`.

Comment: As per Richie's comment, your `data_long %>% ...` line doesn't save the result. That might be why you can't subsequently access the `status` column. To fix: `data_long <- data_long %>% ...`